# Print only parts that match regex

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

`echo "a b _c d _e f" | sed 's/[ ]*_[a-z]\+//g'`

The result will be `a b d f`.

Now, how can I turn it around, and only print `_c _e`, while assuming nothing about the rest of the line?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If the question is "How can I print only substrings that match specific a regular expression using `sed`?" then it will be really hard to achieve (and not an obvious solution).

`grep` could be more helpful in that case. The `-o` option prints each matching part on a separate line, `-P` enables PCRE regex syntax:

```
$> echo "a b _c d _e f" | grep -o -P "(\ *_[a-z]+)"
 _c
 _e
```

And finally

```
$> echo `echo "a b _c d _e f" | grep -o -P "(\ *_[a-z]+)"`
_c _e
```

Comment: debian grep doesn't seem to have `-P` compiled in :-/

Comment: Also on macOS, use: `grep -o -E ...`

Answer (score 5):

Identify the patterns you want, surrounded by the patterns you don't want, and emit only those:

```
echo "a b _c d _e f" | sed 's/[^_]*\s*\(_[a-z]\)[^_]*/\1 /g'
```

OUTPUT:

```
_c _e
```

Answer (score 1):

Its *hacky* but you can use this for sed only version:

```
echo "a b _c d _e f" | sed 's/ /\
/g' | sed -n '/_[a-z]/p'
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
_c
_e
```